# Should I fetch the data managed by a plugin by using its APIs or Wordpress APIs?

Tags: plugins, templates

I am learning Wordpress for the first time since a couple weeks or so, and to make practice and create something useful, I've started a pizza restaurant website, which perhaps I'll also publish.

To explain myself in the shortest possible way, I'm currently editing some of the default [MotoPress Restaurant Menu plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/mp-restaurant-menu/) templates to make the site look like I'd want. First, the plugin offered a menu listing template, but I had no idea on how to sort the elements, how to filter them, and how to achieve a table-like display instead of a list of `<div>`s inside the page. What I did to "improve" this template was creating a custom `page-menu-lb.php` template file and adding there code for populating a `<table>` with data from the database.

To fetch the data from the database, instead, I created some files and classes which use Wordpress API function/classes like `WP_Query` and the `(wp)_get_*` functions; further, I also modelled a `Pizza` class to store data in an object-oriented way. With this, I was able to construct a menu page the way I intended.

[image]

Now that I also have to display posts for single items (in my case, pizzas) I have to modify other template files of the kind `single-{post-type}.php`. I know more than a couple of ways to do it, but what is the most *idiomatic* and "correct" in Wordpress?

My two final questions are therefore:

1. How should I fetch the data from the database? I saw that internally the plugin does it by calling its own functions - it has a kind of little framework inside. Should I use them, or do I risk upgrades incompatibilities? Or should I limit myself to querying the database by using the `WP_Query`, `wpdb` classes and the `(wp)_get_*` functions?
2. Should I modify the plugin default templates by implementing action and filter hooks as recommended by the [succinct plugin documentation](http://www.getmotopress.com/documentation/wordpress/plugins/restaurant-menu/override-templates/), or create custom templates?

Answer (score 1):

I'll answer myself after having completed my two points in the last few days of work:

1. My plugin, which indeed did all of the data insertion and management work, contained some very handy APIs in its codebase. WordPress does also provide [some very great database access APIs (amongst other things)](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference) and I can say that I used them interchangeably. In general, I gave priority over the plugin functions, but if I didn't find a useful API it was easy constructing one myself on top of WordPress'. However, I never used direct MySQL queries, like through the [wpdb](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb) class.
2. I also needed to define templates for single menu items, which actually were posts. In the only one case so far, I created a `single-mp_menu_item.php` template file within my child theme directory, and I modified code pasted there from the parent theme to suit my needs. What is important to note though, is that I did not resort to using action and filter hooks as recommended by the plugin documentation.